# Should I preload images in java like this?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I need to read an image from the file and convert it into `BufferedImage` using `ImageIO` like this:

```
BufferedImage temp = ImageIO.read(new File("temp.png"));
```

This will be repeated about 30 times in 1 second with many different files. I am worried that those will be uploaded late. Should I preload them into arrays or lists like this?

```
BufferedImage temp[]; //Or List<BufferedImage>
for(i=0;i<30;i++){
    temp[i] =  = ImageIO.read(new File("temp.png"));
}
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked it to see how long it takes? Are the images all the same size or are they variable sizes?

Comment: @Jason 
I benchmarked them and the difference in speed was negligible. This can be repeated many times and I'm worried about them taking up too much memory and causing the speed to drop.

Comment: @Jason  And they have a variable size

Comment: Well yeah this can be fairly memory consuming and slow, it took 2.5 seconds to load 30 images that are all 256x256 in a single thread. If you wanted you could probably break this up to a few threads to do the reading independently. That being said, need a bit more context.

Comment: @Jason I am using them to create an animation. Each animation needs about 30 `BufferedImage`, I need 10 animations like that. That means that 300 `BufferedImage` will need to be preloaded. 1 image about 10 kb in size.

Comment: You might want to look into sprite sheets. The idea behind them is you can load only what you need and then dispose of what you don't from a single image. You're going to have to update the main post with what libraries or frameworks you're using, the  attempt you made, etc.